# Properly remove sockets accidentally created with tmux

Tags: tmux, nfs, socket

I just started using `tmux`; out of muscle memory (was a `screen` user) I tried to create a new session like this: `tmux -S mySession`, and after I detached, a socket named `mySession=` appeared in my working directory. I just `rm`ed it and now there's a stale file handle like `.nfs00000000014e6d6b000160d2=` which I can't remove (`Device or resource busy`).

Comment: Perhaps that file is being used by the tmux session you detached?  Did you try to quit the detached window to see if the file disappears?

Comment: It's still there even after I `kill-server`; according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333291/is-it-possible-to-find-tmux-sockets-currently-in-use), "tmux keeps these sockets around for some amount of time even if no current tmux session is using them."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file such as `.nfs00000000014e6d6b000160d2` is generated whenever an *open* file is deleted from an NFS mounted filesystem.

In your case you'll still have a `tmux` background process running.  If you do a `ps ax` you'll see it.  If you kill that off then the file will be closed and *should* be autocleaned.

Comment: Did the trick, thanks. Somehow it didn't occur to me that tmux still runs in the background after detaching/kill-server

Comment: `tmux kill-server` works based on the `$TMUX` variable to talk to the background process.  If it's not set or pointing elsewhere then the "lost" process is not told to die.